# Eclipse error:cannot opn .obj file

Tags: eclipse

I'm using CDT plugin for eclipse for C/C+ development. But i'm not able to compile code it shows following error LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'
What could be reasons?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to make sure to get your sources and generate your object files in a path with no space (not like "`C:\Program Files (x86)\...`")

The other workaround would be to check in the settings of the project if you can add double-quotes around any path defined. Check also the content of the `.project` file itself.